# updating javascript object key value

Tags: javascript

If i try to add more keys with values to a javascript object it alters the value of all keys, not just the one I have added.

```
var corridorObject = {};
var makeObjects = [];
function someFunction(){
    var a = makePoints;
    var Corridor = viewer.entities.add({
        corridor : {
            positions : (a),
            width : 10.0,
            material : Cesium.Color.GREEN,
        }
        var idv0 = Corridor.id
        corridorObject[idv0] = makeObjects;
        console.log(corridorObject);
        makeObjects.length=0;
    }
```

The Corridor ID is a guid, the makeObjects an array of objects, when I run this it adds the key perfectly, and the values, but when I run it a second time it adds a new key with the new ID and new values, but it also changes the values for all the other keys to the most recent values.

here is the console, as you can see the first time the array for the ID is 3 long the second time with the same id its 2 long

```
Object {91ff9967-7019-4e76-846e-c0e125481060: Array[3]}
Object {91ff9967-7019-4e76-846e-c0e125481060: Array[2], 3de2c2b1-5fb6-495c-9034-2b37713e5c30: Array[2]}
```

Sorry to be more clear, this is from Cesiumjs, its taking points and converting them to a corridor, the corridor id and an array of the points that made it are then added to this object. The array of points is then emptied.

Comment: Can you show some output?

Comment: what is the resultant structure you want?

Comment: You're making all the values be the same array object.

Comment: what do you mean by 'run second time'? can you add more code to your snippet? If you have array of objects then precisely you have an array of references to the objects. Modifying one will modify others.

Answer (score 0):

If you are repeating

```
var corridorObject = {};
var makeObjects = [];
var idv0 = Corridor.id
corridorObject[idv0] = makeObjects;
console.log(corridorObject);
```

These line of code then It will initialise

```
var corridorObject = {};
```

Thats why you will get only one key. Put initialization outside of the iteration

Comment: I have updated my explanation, the object initialization was outside of the function, sorry for my poor initial explanation. Any further suggestions?